# Automated testing with TFS - Fully run tests on all registered Agents

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs, hyper-v

I´ve set up a virtual environment for automatic testing using TFS, Hyper-V and so on.

On my Hper-V machine i so far have 4 VMs running, all different Windows editions. (XP, Vista and 2x Win7)

My plan is to run all of my coded tests on each virtual machine. Somehow all VMs are being used for testing, but the tests get split up and not every test is being executed on every VM.

Eg. i have 736 written tests and 4 VMs running to execute the tests, then each VM only executes 184 tests, like there was some load balancing enabled.

Instead i want all 736 tests being executed on each running VM.

Is there something i missed or am i completely going about it the wrong way?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "load balancing" behaviour you are seeing is the intended default behaviour.  If you want to run all tests against each test agent, you will need to configure the test agents with attributes that allow them to be distinguished from one another, then configure your build to run the tests 4 times, each with a distinct test settings that targets one of the four test agents.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I configured the test agents with different attributes, however I did not find a way to configure my build definition to run the tests 4 times after a build and also no way to automatically make the test settings change after every test run. When i open the build definition I only have the option to provide one single *.testsettings file and also no option to set how many times the tests should be executed. Can you please provide some more detailed information on how to do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: In your build definition, you need to add four separate test sets, each one using a different .testssettings file.  To add a test set, select the "Automated Tests" line in the build process settings, which will cause an elipsis button to appear at the end of the line.  Clicking the elipsis button will allow you to add new test sets.

Comment: Thanks again. Works just fine, but allow me one final question... Is it possible to run all the test sets at the same time. Looks like its running the fist test on one VM and then the second one on the second VM. Simultanious test execution on all configured VMs would be the final goal.

Comment: If your goal is to reduce the overall build time, you could try changing your build process template to run the test sets in a ParallelForEach<T> task instead of a ForEach<T> task.  (N.B.: I've never done this, so I'm not sure that it would work, but it's a relatively easy thing to try.)  However, if these aren't true unit tests, and you're actually trying to do load testing, you might want to consider looking into the TFS load testing functionality instead.

Comment: This is not for load testing. Its "simply" a nightly build and then running all available unit and coded UI tests at the same time on all virtual machines hosted on the standalone Hyper-V server to get the tests done as quickly as possible and at a high frequency. Test cases are going to explode over time and all the tests need to be executed on VMs representing all of our supported Windows OS since Windows XP SP3, 32 and 64 bit editions. So, there´s many tests on many virtual machines. If simply all tests within the build definition and the linked

Comment: testsettings files would be executed one after the other, then there would always be only one VM being in use on the "big" Hyper-V server instead of all of them at the same time. I will try to follow your last post and get it to run this way. Thanks a lot for your kind support. Keep you posted about my progress.

Comment: Got it going the way i need it. I created a new build process template and in the section where the tests are executed i replaced the ForEach<T> with a ParallelForEach<T> as suggested by you, Nicole. Works like a charm! Thank you for your great support.

Comment: Hi @SonicSuperfly, how did this work for you? Do you have multiple Build Agents or Test Agent on the build machine? 

Cos this throws the following error for: 
 TF900546: An unexpected error occurred while running the RunTests activity: 'Could not execute the tests as there is already an active test run.'

Obs: Based on DefaultTemplate.11.1 i already configured a one and two agent, build controller.

Comment: @AdeAlejo Based on the comment's dates I assume you use TFS2012 and SonicSuperfly used TFS2010. I have not yet tried it myself, but [apparently](http://blog.bbv.ch/2014/01/28/reducing-build-process-time-by-using-multicore-platforms-in-tfs-2012/#comment-187134) this doesn't work no longer with VSTest, which is the new default test runner in TFS2012+. You could try to use the MSTest-Runner instead; if possible (mind you that one does not support adapters, e.g. for NUnit).